# How to create exported functions in Mono.Cecil?

Tags: c#, mono, mono.cecil, kernel32

What am I doing wrong? I'm trying to create an exported function of LoadLibraryA and inject it into an assembly.

```
TypeReference stringType = asm.MainModule.Import(typeof(String)); 
TypeReference nativeIntType = asm.MainModule.Import(typeof(IntPtr));
ModuleReference kernel32Ref = new ModuleReference("kernel32");

asm.MainModule.ModuleReferences.Add(kernel32Ref);
MethodDefinition loadLibraryA = new MethodDefinition("LoadLibraryA", Mono.Cecil.MethodAttributes.Public |
            Mono.Cecil.MethodAttributes.HideBySig | Mono.Cecil.MethodAttributes.Static |
            Mono.Cecil.MethodAttributes.PInvokeImpl, nativeIntType);

        loadLibraryA.PInvokeInfo = new PInvokeInfo(PInvokeAttributes.NoMangle | PInvokeAttributes.CharSetAnsi
            | PInvokeAttributes.SupportsLastError | PInvokeAttributes.CallConvWinapi, "LoadLibraryA", kernel32Ref);

        loadLibraryA.Parameters.Add(new ParameterDefinition("name", Mono.Cecil.ParameterAttributes.None, stringType));
```

Comment: We can't know what's wrong if you don't tell what's going wrong? What's the error? Are you getting an exception? Or is the pinvoke not in the resulting assembly?

Comment: @Jb Evain The exception was FileNotFoundException when I loaded it in another application as reference. Even though now I fixed it, it still shows the exception when using it in another assembly, but it's working internally.

Comment: Also you may want to use kernel32.dll as a module reference instead of kernel32 alone.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, I found the solution. The entry point is suppose to be `LoadLibrary` not `LoadLibraryA`. I wonder why I did that.....

Also I didn't do this:

```
loadLibraryA.IsPreserveSig = true;
```

The charset also needs to be unicode not ansi...